# Localizing the Content Query Web Part in XSL

Tags: 2007, content-query-web-part, xslt

Has anyone managed to get the locale ID for the context of an instance of a Content Query Web Part in XSL, without extending the class?

DataViewWebParts have a Language parameter passed in, but CQWP doesn't have this.

Even if there's a way to pass in the LCID via the CommonViewFields somehow would make it accessable in the XSL...

(This is all for MOSS).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use ParameterBindings to this purpose.

```
<ParameterBinding Name="Language" Location="Resource(wss,language_value)" />
```

This will return "en-us" for English locale in xsl:param "Language". Also, you can pass whole resource values this way.

You can read more about this in Stefan Stanev's blog:

http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.com/2010/09/xsltlistviewwebpart-contentbyquerywebpa.html

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I was after. Cheers!

Comment: This is great, however I can't find the Language_value key on the wss resource file, did you do it manually ? thanks

Comment: no, it's ootb in my `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\App_GlobalResources\wss.resx` file.